# How to call the function in backend in Node.js & koa2

Tags: node.js, koa

I use Node.js, koa2 and ejs to build a website, and there's a function like following

in app.js

```
mysqOptlModel.getAllRecords()
.then(async(result) => {
   await ctx.render('AllRecordsView', {
       allrecords:result
   })
})
```

in `list.ejs` of the frontend

```
<% allrecords.forEach(function(item, i){%>
<tr>
  <td><%=item.username%></td>
  <td><%=item.createdtime%></td>
</tr>
<%})%>
```

**Here are my questions**

1. I don't want to show the full username, I just want to show some parts, and some is instead by *
2. The createdtime is timestamp format, and I want to change it to Date format

**My current solution**

I write two JavaScript function in `list.ejs`, and call them to use.

**My expectation**

I want to do this in `app.js`, not in list.ejs

Is there any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a way to modify your result in `app.js`:

```
mysqOptlModel.getAllRecords()
    .then(async(result) => {

        // here the modification happens
        modifiedResult = result.map((item) => { 
            return {
                username: item.username.substr(0,3) + '*****', 
                date: new Date(item.createdtime).toISOString().substr(0,10)
            }
        })

        await ctx.render('AllRecordsView', {
            allrecords:modifiedResult           // pass the modified result
        })
    })
```